# How do I display things in a label in wpf application?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

So I'm supposed to be making a wpf application for my netd class and literally every other part of the program works fine my only problem is getting the calculated pay to display in a label. This is much different from windows forms and none of the labels actually have names used so I can't get my number to display in the label.

I've already tried using label.content(employeePay) and label.text(employeePay) but neither of those work. I have like three different labels so I can't decipher the different ones to display the employeePay.

```
Private Sub findPay()

    If (employeeMessages >= 1 And employeeMessages <= 2499) Then
        employeePay = CDec(employeeMessages * 0.018)
    End If

    If (employeeMessages >= 2500 And employeeMessages <= 4999) Then
        employeePay = CDec(employeeMessages * 0.024)
    End If

    If (employeeMessages >= 5000 And employeeMessages <= 7499) Then
        employeePay = CDec(employeeMessages * 0.03)
    End If

    If (employeeMessages >= 7500 And employeeMessages <= 10000) Then
        employeePay = CDec(employeeMessages * 0.035)
    End If

    If (employeeMessages > 10000) Then
        employeePay = CDec(employeeMessages * 0.04)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: *"none of the labels actually have names used"*.  So use names then.  *"I've already tried using label.content(employeePay) and label.text(employeePay)"*.  Why would you think that that would work?  They're properties, not methods.  Setting a property is the same no matter whether the object is a WPF control, a WinForms control or not a control at all.

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [ask] sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
  Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852)

Answer (score 1):

As I have said several times, there is a `Name` property. It is listed in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label?view=netframework-4.8#properties) and it is displayed at the top of the Properties window.

[image]

As for setting a property in code, if you had looked at your existing WinForms project properly then you would have seen that you did not do this:

```
MyLabel.Text(newText)
```

but rather this:

```
MyLabel.Text = newText
```

That's how you would have set any property at all in your WinForms app and that's how you set any property at all in any type of app.  The fact that this is a WPF app has exactly zero bearing on how you set a property.

So, as I have already said several times, the solution to your problem is to set a `Name` for your `Label` and then set the appropriate property in code rather than trying to call it as a method.  You already know what the appropriate property is because you already put it in your question, i.e. `Content`.  Like I said, you already had ALL the information you needed but you were simply determined not to use it.  I'd suggest not doing that in future.